# How to pass value from get_queryset() to get_context_data()

Tags: django, django-queryset

As `get_queryset()` returns only one queryset and I need the length of the queryset `search_store` to the template file. So, I'm trying to send the value to the template through `get_context_data`.

I know I can get a length of a queryset through `{{ queryset|length }}`, but for some reason, it only returns a length of queryset separated by pagination, so I only get a partial length.

As you see the code, I'm trying to print `search_stores.count()`, and I need get it in `get_context_data` from `get_queryset`. Can anyone let me know how I can do that?

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = Store
    template_name = 'boutique/search.html'
    paginate_by = 2
    context_object_name = 'search_stores'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search_text'] = self.request.GET.get('search_text')
        context['sorter'] = self.request.GET.get('sorter')
        if not context['sorter']:
            context['sorter'] = 'popularity'
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):

        search_text = self.request.GET.get('search_text')
        sorter = self.request.GET.get('sorter')

        if not sorter:
            sorter = 'popularity'

        if search_text:
            search_stores = Store.objects.filter(Q(businessName__icontains=search_text) | Q(mKey__icontains=search_text))
            if sorter == 'businessName':
                search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter)
            else:
                search_stores = search_stores.order_by(sorter).reverse()
        else:
            search_stores = ''

        for store in search_stores:
            store.mKey = store.mKey.split(' ')

        print(search_stores.count())
        return search_stores
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a list view is paginated, you can access the paginator in the template context with `paginator`.

Therefore you can access the length of the entire (unpaginated) queryset with:

```
{{ paginator.count }}
```

As an aside, your `get_queryset` method should always return a list or a queryset. When `search_text` is not specified, you could return an empty queryset, `Store.objects.none()`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    ...

    if search_text:
        ...
    else:
        search_stores = Store.objects.none()

    return search_stores
```

I would also avoid looping over the queryset to set `store.mKey = store.mKey.split(' ')`. This will evaluate the *entire* queryset, not just the page that you are displaying. It might be better to add a property to your model, for example:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def mkey_list(self):
        return self.mKey.split(' ')
```

Then in your template you can do something like:

```
{% for key in store.mkey_list %}
   {{ key }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm and thank you for the extra advice too! It helped me a lot

Answer (score 6):

if question is "How to pass value from get_queryset() to get_context_data()",
then `get_queryset()` returns `object_list` and you can access it following way:

```
    def get_context_data(self):
        .....
        something = self.object_list
        .....
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the answer I needed.

Comment: If you are using **pagination** you can access the *current page*'s object list by using `context['page_obj']` within `get_context_data()`. Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{ queryset.count }} instead of {{ queryset|length }}

Comment: doesn't this boil down to the same? it will always show the number of objects of the current page... whereas @Jay actually wants the total

Comment: Yes, correct I need the total number, but length returns only partial number based on each pagination. Also, I don't know why but count returns nothing

Comment: count works perfectly for me , just tried ! ...... count uses  SQL request with count(*)

Comment: Yeah, usually count worked for me too, but I don't know why it just returns nothing here..